# PyCharm throws Error "No module named pymongo"

Tags: python, mongodb, pycharm, pymongo

I'm new to Python and just want to connect to MongoDB.
When trying to install pymongo, cmd tells me that the "requirement is already satisfied".
When trying to import pymongo in Pycharm, however, the ModuleNotFoundError is thrown.

I've reinstalled PyCharm with no change.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: How are you importing pymongo?

Comment: IIRC you have to import mongodb again in pycharm because it works with virtual environments

Comment: Did you install pymongo to the same `python` that PyCharm is using?

Comment: In PyCharm go to Settings>>Your project>>Project interpreter and check whether mongo is in the list of installed packages.

Comment: include the import statement you are using in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Settings => Project: => Project Interpreter**
look for packages and install pymongo package

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: thanks, apparently I selected the wrong interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You may have more than one version of python installed in your device and install library in one of them. Type in cmd "where python" and you can see all versions. If you have some version,  you need to configure a desire [Python interpreter in pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html).